# not show data to click on other button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am clicking on many clone button but when i click the first button then data is show and after that, I click the other button data is not show

```
$(function(){
  $("#draggableSignatures").draggable().resizable({
    appendTo: '#documentContainer',
    scroll: false,
    helper: "clone" }); 

  $("#draggableSignatures").on('click',function(event){
    $("#draggableSignatures").clone().appendTo("#documentContainer").draggable().resizable();

    $("#draggableSignatures").click(function () {
      $("#signatureBox").toggle();
  });

  });
});
```

Comment: Please, take a look at [ask] and try to add a [mcve] to us, so we can test, debug and help much better. At moment, it seems a little unclear, for me, what you are trying to do and what is the expected result

Comment: It looks like you are trying to clone elements, and you are trying to create multiple event bindings based off of id selectors.  There are two issues with this.  #1) IDs are expected to unique per page.  `$('#id')` will only ever find one element.  You should use a class rather than an id, if it is expected to repeat on the page.  #2) Rather than duplicating bindings, make a delegate event binding that will work for all of them.